# Обращение к self в методе init

Tags: ios, objective-c

Как будет правильнее инициализировать свойства объектов в методе **init** - обращаться к свойству напрямую через подчеркивание или через **self**?

Единственную опасность в обращении к **self** вижу только есть нет проверки **if (self)**, а необходимость использовать **_obj = @"name";** только если каким то чудом свойство надо инициализировать раньше, чем сам объект

пример:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.nameString = @"name";
        _nameString = @"name";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple рекомендует всегда в инитах использовать подчеркивание, мотивируя это тем, что:

> You should always access the instance variables directly from within
>   an initialization method because at the time a property is set, the
>   rest of the object may not yet be completely initialized. Even if you
>   don’t provide custom accessor methods or know of any side effects from
>   within your own class, a future subclass may very well override the
>   behavior.

Перевод:

> Из методов инициализации вы должны всегда обращаться к переменным
>   инстанса напрямую, потому что во время, когда свойство задается,
>   другие части объекта могут быть еще не полностью инициализированны.
>   Даже если вы не предоставляете кастомных методов доступа, или уверены
>   в отсутствии побочных эффектов в вашем классе, сабклассы в будущем
>   могут создать подобное поведение.

Взято из [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW11).

При этом от себя хочу добавить, что всегда делаю через self, проблем пока не возникало.

Comment: сразу все стало понятно, спасибо